# PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR C2DM on Ice cream sandwich AVD

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I try to run my `C2DM` application in ice cream sandwich `AVD`, but it prompt `PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR` during the `C2DM` registration.

The same code working fine on `froyo/gingerbread`

anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: good question ... (i got the same error) seems like the bug for me... remeber to use Google API version for C2DM and register google account in emulator for C2DM .. i did some research in google and i didn't find anything

Comment: Yes, the AVD is running on Google API vesion 14

Answer (score 1):

This is an error code returned from Google's C2DM servers. [Documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/lv-LV/android/c2dm/#handling_reg) says:

> PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR Incorrect phone registration with Google.
>   This phone doesn't currently support C2DM.

So, *I guess*, C2DM currently simply hasn't been enabled on 4.0 AVD.