# GCM - PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR on Android Emulator

Tags: android, cloud, emulation, messaging

i'm testing GCM with the Google GCM Demo files. The Demo is working fine on my device, but when i try to test it on the Android emulator i get the following error:

```
From GCM: error (PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR)
```

In LogCat it says:

```
D/GCMBaseIntentService(566): handleRegistration: registrationId = null, error = PHONE_REGISTRATION_ERROR, unregistered = null
```

The emulator is running on Adnroid 2.3.3 and a Google Account is added. The problem just showed up yesterday. Last week it was working without any problems. I haven't changed anything in the code, so i don't know where this error is coming from. I also rebootet the emulator and deleted the image and created a new one, without success.

Has anybody an idea what the problem is?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

I think it check the SIM card but the emulator doesn't have any so it throw this exception.

Comment: I don't think that this is the problem, because the emulator worked fine last week.

Comment: In this case, sorry for giving you wrong informations.
But maybe this post can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887090/phone-registration-error-c2dm-on-ice-cream-sandwich-avd

Comment: Thx for the link, but this doesn't help neither. In this post it says that the emulator maybe doesn't support GCM. But as i said earlier, with same Android version + Google API version it worked last week.

Comment: In my case, it actually was the sim card